# Check if onChange works correctly with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to test if ParameterLabel value changed when onChange event was tested.
Something is missing on this line:

expect(wrapper.state('ParameterLabel'))).toEqual("ParameterLabel value"); //??

I need to add context somewhere after wrapper.state, so it can check the value inside of ParamenterLabel and perform the change
Using Shallow -   Jest / enzyme

```
it('Testing ParameterLabel onBlur event ', () => {
 baseProps.onBlur.mockClear();
 wrapper.setState({
    context:{
      ParameterLabel:'test',
      PARAMETER_TYPE: {
          ParameterTypeId:'ParameterLabel-Test'
        },
      PARAMETER_DATATYPE:{
          DataTypeId:'test'
        },
     },
  });
  wrapper.update() 
  wrapper.find('input[id="ParameterLabel"]').simulate('blur',{
    target: { 
       value:'ParameterLabel value', 
       id: 'ParameterLabel'
     }
 });
   expect(wrapper.state('ParameterLabel'))).toEqual("ParameterLabel value"); //??
});


<input id='ParameterLabel' className='user-value-field' onBlur={this.updateContext} defaultValue={this.state.context.ParameterLabel}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components .Which in this case state would access context and not ParameterLabel

Comment: I am assuming your component is a class based component ?

Comment: @Utsav Patel correct. Is there a way when you are testing set state to access what is inside, in this case, whatever is inside of context

Comment: This should work as expected. Can you provide a minimal working codepen or codesandbox which has this issue ?

Comment: I will try to set it up a codesandbox soon , thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your setState call, it looks like the state property 'ParameterLabel' is nested inside of 'context'.

Try searching for the 'context' object inside your assertion then pulling out that property. Something like:

```
expect(wrapper.state('context').ParameterLabel)).toEqual("ParameterLabel value");
```

Comment: I tried already too, get the following message: ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components